# Using like or ilike to create SQL/ PLpgSQL function

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-like

I am trying to create function Animals (for convenience purpose) that takes first letter of an animal name and returns the whole name of the animal from the list e.g. C=> Cow, Cat... The problem I am facing is that the string after the like function is being treated as a string (I want it to be input).
The following didn't work.

```
create function
   Animalfun(input text) returns text
as $$
SELECT name
FROM Animals
WHERE name like 'input%';
$$ language sql;

select name from Animals where name = Animalfun('A');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT name FROM Animals WHERE name like input || '%'
```

Comment: Indeed, just a bit of twist and it works. Thanks a lot.